# DFS output all matching elements and its ancestor : javascript

Tags: recursion, tree, depth-first-search, ancestor

Given

```
//  tree data structure
Elephant --> Duck
         --> Hamster -->  Elephant1
                     -->  Elephant2

Hamster --> Elephant --> Fish
        --> Dog -------> Elephant

Dog --> Unicorn
    --> Fish --> Hamster
             --> Elephant --> Elephant
```

---

when user type term 'Ele', would like to output result so that all the tree is reduced to the following format (which has the matching result with its ancestor)

```
Elephant --> Hamster -->  Elephant1
                     -->  Elephant2  
Hamster --> Elephant 
        --> Dog -------> Elephant
Dog --> Fish  --> Elephant --> Elephant
```

Given

```
this.tree = [
    { id:1, name: 'Elephant',children:[ 
          { id:2, name: 'Duck' },
          { id:3, name: 'Hamster', children: [
                   { id: 4, name: 'Elephant1', id: 5, name: 'Elephant2' }]
          }
    ]},
    { id:5A, name: 'Hamster', children: [
          { id:6, name: 'Elephant', children: [
                  { id:7, name: 'Fish' }
          ]},
          { id:8, name: 'Dog', children: [
                  { id:9, name: 'Elephant' }
          ]}
    ]},
    { id:10, name: 'Dog', children: [
          { id:11, name: 'Unicorn' },
          { id:12, name: 'Fish', children: [
                  { id:13, name: 'Hamster' },
                  { id:14, name: 'Elephant', children: 
                         [{ id:15, name: 'Elephant' }
                  ]},
          ]}
    ]},
    { id:16, name: 'Elephant', children: [
          { id:17, name: 'Duck' }, 
          { id:18, name: 'Hamster', children: [
                 { id:19, name: 'Elephant' }, 
                 { id:20, name: 'Fish' }
          ]}
    ]}
]
```

---

My attempt:

I have tried the following using Depth First Search traversal but having issue to include its ancestor when its children has matching term. Currently the code only prints the matching result of the children but not its ancestor. I am half way through the solution (probably need some slight modification on my attempt solution) but is having trouble in the backtracking. Have been searching for resources on DFS and Would appreciate if anybody know about this.

```
onSearch(term) {
    let found = this.search(term, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tree)));
    console.log(found);
}

search(term, parent, path, basket) {
    let fork = path.slice(0);

    let found, { name, id, children } = parent;
    let nameId = name + ':' +id;

    fork.push(nameId);
    if (name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) !== -1) {
        basket.push(fork);
        fork = [];
        return basket
    } 
    if (!!children && children.length > 0) {
        for (let child of parent.children) {
            this.search(term, child, fork, basket)  
        }
        return basket;
    } 

    if (children.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }
  }

this.onSearch('elep');
```

However the above attempt solution return the below result which is not exactly right.

```
Elephant  --> Hamster -->  Elephant1 

Hamster --> Elephant  
        --> Dog -------> Elephant

Dog  --> Fish  --> Elephant
```

Desire solution is to output

```
Elephant --> Hamster -->  Elephant1
                     -->  Elephant2  
Hamster --> Elephant 
        --> Dog -------> Elephant
Dog --> Fish  --> Elephant --> Elephant
```

Answer (score 0):

After few attempts, found the following solution which will output the desire solution

```
onSearch(term) {
   let found = this.search(term, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tree)));
   console.log(found);
}
search(term, parent, path, basket) {
    let found, { name, id, children } = parent;
    let nameId = name + ':' +id;

    let fork = path.slice(0);
    fork.push(nameId);

    if (name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) !== -1) {
        basket.push([fork]);
    } 
    if (!!children && children.length > 0) {
        for (let child of parent.children) {
            this.search(term, child, fork, basket)
        }
        return basket;
    } 
}
```